# List all local commits in the current branch that have not been pushed to remote for Git tool

Tags: git, git-branch

I am creating a simple git viewer in PHP and I need a way to list and count all the commits that have not been pushed to my Bitbucket account from the current branch.

I tried using:

```
git cherry -v
```

This does give me a list of commits, but the list contains both pushed and un-pushed

After looking at a couple of other questions I tried:

```
git log @{u}..
```

This gives me the same result.

Other answers need the name of the branch in the command, where I want to return results for the current HEAD branch.

Comment: Using `git log --oneline <remote>/<branch>..<reference>` will show you all commits in `<reference>` that aren't in the remote branch. That's basically what `git log @{u}..` does, except your current HEAD needs to be tracking a remote branch for that particular form to work. **However**, I'm not sure if `git log` is the right tool to be using for a custom built git GUI, since it's generally a high-level UI porcelain command, rather than low-level plumbing, meaning it's not guaranteed to be backwards compatible with future versions of Git.

Comment: for me git `cherry -v` gives exactly what you want (and what's said in the MAN) - _git-cherry - Find commits yet to be applied to upstream_

Comment: You'll find a list of low-level Git commands [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html#_low_level_commands_plumbing). I'm sure that there must be someway to use a combination of them to do what you want, in a way that's future-compatible with future-versions of Git.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt was correct and should provide you the information you are looking for, here is the same command with additional options in order to specify the desired `<upstream>` and `<head>`:

```
git cherry -v origin/master master
```

Notice that the result is showed with the most recent commit at the top (the opposite as the `git log` command).

Your problem may be caused by the position of your `HEAD`, use this command to have a clear view of your log:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate
```

Hope that this will help you to identify and solve your problem.